# Create two vectors contain the same elements in different order

Tags: c++, stdvector

Is it possible to create a vector from elements of another vector so that changing an element by index in one of the vectors results in a change in the corresponding element in the second vector?

```
std::vector<double> temp_1 = {1, 4};
std::vector<double> temp_2;
temp_2.resize(3);
temp_2[0] = temp_1[1];
temp_2[1] = temp_1[0];
temp_1[0] = 55;
>>> temp_1 =[55,4] 
>>> temp_2 =[4,55]
```

Comment: No that is not possible.

Comment: You could create a vector of indices.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes that migh work, but it is still an extra indirection (just like pointers)

Comment: What are you trying to do? It feels like double administration and that is bound to be buggy.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I have two relative vectors of matrix values in one class. First vector for CSC representation and second for CSR representation of the same matrix. So I want the changes in the values in one vector to change the values in the other, because in fact these are the values of the same matrix.

Comment: vector of shared_ptr would work

Comment: It would be just as easy to store your sparse matrix as a COO and convert to/from CSR and CSC as needed.

Comment: If the matrices are of known size, you can use the idea in the answer. But then use std::array of std::array. Or you can make a wrapper class that contains both matrices and has setters/getters that operate on both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can be done using pointers or reference wrappers, though note that any reallocation of the referenced vector will render the references invalid. However, if no reallocations are involved, it should be fine.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    std::vector<int> x{1,2,3};
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> y {
        x[2], x[0], x[1]
    };

    std::cout << "y before modifying x\n";
    for (auto el: y) {
        std::cout << el << '\n';
    }

    x[1] = 8;
    std::cout << "y after modifying x\n";
    for (auto el: y) {
        std::cout << el << '\n';
    }

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/d41nxPffz